# iTerm2 still opens old shell after Bash upgrade

Tags: bash, iterm

I tried upgrading my MacOS Bash from 3.2 to the latest version as in [this article](https://itnext.io/upgrading-bash-on-macos-7138bd1066ba).

It involves installing the latest Bash with Homebrew and then setting the default shell with `chsh`. However, `chsh` doesn't appear to work with iTerm2 -- iTerm2 still is opening the old shell when I make a new tab. I see that there's an option in iTerm to to set the launch command, but I'm wondering if there isn't a better way... It is supposed to work across the board once its set as my login shell.

Can anyone tell me what I'm missing?

Comment: i followed the directions in the file you linked and it appears to have worked fine. If I start iterm and type bash --version  i get version 5.03 returned. if i open a new window or a new tab they all are version 5 of bash.

Comment: one thing i did differently, which shouldn't matter, is I did mot use Vim to edit the file as per the line:"sudo vim /etc/shells". I used a different editor but that shouldn't matter.

Comment: But you did use sudo though?